# DJIRTKState:distanceToHomePointDataSource is of type DJIRTKDataSource instead of a distance type

Tags: dji-sdk

The DJI documentation for DJIRTKState:distanceToHomePointDataSource is as follows

> Distance to home point data source. Only Supported by Phantom 4 RTK.

So its reasonable to expect a double or some sort of the type which is used to represent distance. But the type for DJIRTKState:distanceToHomePointDataSource is declared as DJIRTKDataSource which is an enum. DJI support, is this a bug?